Remove `View post` Text
How to remove View post from this message ?
My code is like below.
public function game_updated_messages( $messages )

    {
    
    $messages['game'] = $messages['post'];
    
    $messages['game'][1] = 'Post updated.';
    
    $messages['game'][6] = 'Post published.';
    
    return $messages;
    
    }



wherehow is game_updated_messages called? Is it on a filter if so which ones? I'm assuming this is in the classic editor? It's difficult to tell from the screenshot if it's the classic editor, a quick edit action, or something else. Is game a CPT? If so what are the labels in its registration?

Thanks @TomJNowell. I called it like this add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', [ $this, 'game_updated_messages' ] );. Yes, game is a CPT. How to find the labels in its registration ? Thanks.

can you edit your question to include that information? Labels are provided when you register the post type, look at the code that registers that post type and it'll be obvious, labels usually make up to half the code when registering a post type

I think the issue is this piece of code $messages['game'] = $messages['post'];. $messages will contains all the updated messages for all custom post type. In this case, your CPT is game, so you should change the array item of game only.
The correct code should be
public function game_updated_messages( $messages )
{
    $messages['game'][1] = 'Post updated.';
    $messages['game'][6] = 'Post published.';
    
    return $messages;
}

You can try to dump the variable $messages and see all the result it returns.

Thanks @Dao. I tried your solution. But it is not working.

Thanks @Dao. I dumped the variable $messages. But I am not getting $messages['game']. How can I debug the issue ?
